# simple AJAX request for beginner

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to find some very simple AJAX request for beginners and I haven't find nothing but a little parts of code that doesn't work... Well, could someone help me and tell me what's wrong on this?

My Klient part:

```
<form method="GET" action="" id="f">
    <label for="name">Your name: </label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <input type="submit" onclick="yourName(document.getElementById('name').value)">
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
<script>
    function yourName(str)
    {

        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","f.php?name="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

and server part:

```
<body>

<?php

// Send the data back
echo "Your name is: ".$_GET['name'];

?>
</body>
```

I'm not a big friend of javascript and this is incomprehensible for me :(

Comment: You might find it easier to use `jQuery`'s ajax functions. They are a lot simpler than native JS.

Answer (score 2):

you right javascript.

you need to Change your html:

```
<form method="GET" action="" id="f">
    <label for="name">Your name: </label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <input  value=" submit" type="button" onclick="yourName(document.getElementById('name').value)">
</form>
```

change the type of button. if you use `type="submit"` then when you are pressing it will submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is bound to a click event on a submit button.

When you click it, the Ajax request is sent off and then the form submits (reloading the page) before the response comes back.

Return false from the `onclick` attribute to stop the normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form method="GET" action="" id="f">
    <label for="name">Your name: </label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return yourName(document.getElementById('name').value)">
</form>

<span id="result"></span>

<script>
function yourName(str)
{

    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","f.php?name="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
</script>
```

I assume when you press the submit button the page is being redirected? You need to add a `return` to your `onclick` attribute, then in the actual javascript function, return false so the form isn't submitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you realy want to go raw JS use [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript/), but if you want to make your life easy use JQuery.

First You can use the ajaxForm/ajaxSubmit functions from [Ajax Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) or the jQuery serialize function. (This way you dont need to put any js stuff in HTML except links provided at the bottom)
AjaxForm:

```
$("#f").ajaxForm({url: 'server.php', type: 'get'})
```

or

```
$("#f").ajaxSubmit({url: 'server.php', type: 'get'})
```

ajaxForm will send when the submit button is pressed. ajaxSubmit sends immediately.

Serialize:

```
$.get('f.php?' + $('#f').serialize())

$.post('f.php', $('#f').serialize())
```

[AJAX serialization documentation is here.](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Links to add:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#f" ).submit(function( event ) {
      $.get('f.php?' + $('#f').serialize())
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
    </script>
```

Hope it helps! By the way you can see the response in the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your form since I do not think a submit and action are what you need here:

```
<form method="GET" id="f">
<label for="name">Your name: </label><input type="text" id="name">
<button type="button"    
onclick="yourName(document.getElementById('name').value)">Click</button>
</form>
```

Here's a starter AJAX function you can try:

```
function yourName(str) {
var ajaxRequest;
try {
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e1) {
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e2) {
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e3) {
            alert("Please try again!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
};    
ajaxRequest.open("GET","f.php?name=" + str,true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please remove `type="submit"` from your submit button in order to call ajax script.

Your code working in two ways at that moment; first submitting your page it self and other is calling your js function. So you need to change type of your button with `type="button"` and then on ajax success response you need to add submit finction

like:

```
<input type="type" onclick="yourName(document.getElementById('name').value)">
```

and on ajax code add:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("f").submit();
        } 

    }
```

check above changes and let me know if anything you got wrong after this implementation.

Answer (score -2):

Use JQuery - AJAX request are very simple with it:

```
$.get('f.php?name=' + str, function(result) {
    $("#result").html(result);
});
```

More Informations: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Typical [Not enought jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45176/223068) answer.